# Create a folder/Directory on FTP using Azure-Logic-App

Tags: ftp, azure-logic-apps

I have been facing this issue while creating an azure logic app.

I am extracting a zip file in FTP From one Folder(Source) to Another Folder(Destination)

The FTP connector asks for folder name whenever I want to extract files on FTP server.

E.g: It would put files in /MyDemo/Destination/FolderOut here.

[image]

What I want to achieve is this,

I want a folder(FolderOut in above example) to be created dynamically on FTP and then put files into it.

I tried by putting another folder name which do not exist over there hoping that connector would create it automatically(which I want). But It doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now logic app ftp connector doesn't support create folder, check the [connector reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/ftpconnector/#actions).

You could go to the azure feedback vote up for this feature:[FTP Connector - Create Directory](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps/suggestions/20370421-ftp-connector-create-directory).

Or choose other service like azure storage file or use sftp, they support create folder.

Comment: Thanks but the server I have been working upon is FTP and that can not be changed to SFTP. Can we have a workaround for that (the FTP situation)?

Comment: Maybe you could use a  [function in the logic app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-azure-functions#add-existing-functions-to-logic-apps), use the function to create the directory. Here is a Function sample with FluentFTP.https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/3063#issuecomment-429071290

Comment: @Maulik Modi , if this could help you, please accept it as the answer.